# what is the difference between # and the dot in Jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What is the difference between the `#` and `.` (the dot) in Jquery?

For example, I have seen

```
$('#divName').show();
```

and also

```
$('.divName').append();
```

in our code base, can someone kindly explain? I am a newbie at Jquery.

Comment: it's not about jQuery (mainly) but CSS

Comment: [RTFM](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: replace `$` by `.` in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it's a css selector fundamentally here are example [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

`#` is an element ID selector

`.` is a element class selector

Answer (score 3):

`#` is used to find elements by id, whereas `.` is used to to elements by class name(s).

So `$('#divName')` means: find `div` with id `divName` and `$('.divName')` means find all divs with class `divName`

You can find description of range of selectors at [jQuery API Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 2):

`#` relates to id attribute of an element, and selector returns first occurence only.
`.` relates to class attribute, and returns all elements of the class

Answer (score 1):

The hash (#) is a selector based on an id like `<div id="myid">`
and the dot (.) is a selector based on an class like `<div class="somethingClass">`